# c# How to determine which packet is being received

Tags: c#, sockets

I've made a proxy for Minecraft packets, and I want to start fiddling with them.
The packet id defines which packet it is. Although some packets have the same id as others (not sure why). Here is my code for reading data from the game client and passing it on to the server. The `serverSocket` is connected to the game server, and the `clientSocket` is the game client, which connected through a `TcpListener` in another class.

```
byte[] clientBuffer = new byte[2048];
private void __ClientThread()
{
    while (serverSocket.Connected && clientSocket.Connected)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = clientSocket.Receive(clientBuffer);
            byte[] data = new byte[count];
            Array.Copy(clientBuffer, 0, data, 0, count);

            switch (packet_id)
            {
                case 0x02:
                    // chat packet?
                    break;
            }

            SendToServer(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

My question is this, how can I determine which packet I'm reading?
The packet in question is a raw string with a max length of 255 characters.

Thank you.

Comment: Do not use links to external resources to provide information important to your question. Include _all_ relevant information in your question post itself. As for that question, it's not clear what you're asking, in part because the question lacks sufficient detail (what does this _"id"_ represent and if it's not indicating the type of packet, what should?), and in part because it's not clear whether you understand the limitations of UDP itself (e.g. duplicate datagrams are possible, so you haven't clearly ruled out that you're just getting duplicate datagrams).

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I can't do that. I'll correct it.

Comment: This isn't UDP, it's TCP. The Minecraft protocol has it's own way of handling packets. The packet id is to define the type, but multiple packets in the protocol have the same id. For example, there's a 'Spawn Global Entity' packet with the id 0x02, and the packet I'm trying to read is also 0x02, I'm asking how I tell the two apart.

Comment: The code you posted is not correct for receiving TCP data. And if this is TCP, your question is even less clear, because the code you posted won't reliably receive messages over TCP. And you still haven't explained what this _"id"_ is, nor what it would mean to tell two of the messages apart. Please read [ask], and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page.

Comment: Not sure where you have found the protocol, but the protocol does not allow duplicate id's and you are ignoring the id length (byte 0). http://wiki.vg/Protocol

Comment: Yes but how do I tell which packet I'm reading just from the length? That's why I ignored it. EDIT: Sorry I think I just misunderstood the entire protocol. I feel really really stupid...

Comment: Yeah sorry, I didn't realize that the other packets with that id aren't serverbound.

Comment: You need an application layer.  The client is a master and the server a slave.  So the client sends a command the client processes the command and returns a response.  So first for the application layer you need to create a command language and a response language so you can tell which type message is being transmitter.  Also the command and response needs a terminator like a return character to the end of the message is known.

Comment: _"how do I tell which packet I'm reading just from the length?"_ -- why in the world would you think you could? If I have two files, and I tell you one is 100 bytes long, and the other is 110 bytes long, is that enough information to tell you what kind of file each is? And if I tell you a third file is also 100 bytes long, is that enough information to tell you whether that file is identical to the first or not? I hope you can see that the answers to those questions are all "no", and that the same thing applies to messages sent via network I/O.

Comment: I know that you can't tell the type from the length, that's why I said that. It was more of a "how does that work" then an actual question.